# How to mock a RedisAtomicInteger

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, redis, mockito

I've been trying to create a UnitTest for a method that will track the amount of calls made to an specific server. This is the actual method:

```
public int setCounterOnRedis(int count) {
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
    String currentDate = dtf.format(LocalDate.now());
    RedisAtomicInteger redisAtomicInteger =
      new RedisAtomicInteger(currentDate, redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory());

    return redisAtomicInteger.addAndGet(count);
}
```

And this is the test class:

```
public class CacheServiceTest {

    private CacheService cacheService;
    private RedisTemplate redisTemplate;
    private RedisConnectionFactory connFactory;
    private RedisConnection connection;
    private ValueOperations valueOperations;
    private RedisOperations redisOperations;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        cacheService = spy(CacheService.class);
        redisTemplate = mock(RedisTemplate.class);
        connFactory = mock(RedisConnectionFactory.class);
        connection = mock(RedisConnection.class);
        valueOperations = mock(ValueOperations.class);
        redisOperations = mock(RedisOperations.class);

        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(cacheService, "redisTemplate", redisTemplate);
    }

    @Test
    public void test_validate_redis_counter() {  
        when(redisTemplate.getConnectionFactory())
             .thenReturn(connFactory);
        when(connFactory.getConnection()).thenReturn(connection);
        when(redisTemplate.opsForValue()).thenReturn(valueOperations);
        when(valueOperations.getOperations())
            .thenReturn(redisOperations);

        assertThat(cacheService.setCounterOnRedis(3), is(0));
    }
}
```

The issue that I'm getting is that whenever the constructor in *RedisAtomicInteger* is called the *ValueOptions* is not being mocked properly which ignores the call on methods like *addAndGet()*, hence making the test pass when it should be failing. I've seen some examples but I'm not sure if I'm missing something else.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may want to consider reading [my article here](https://github.com/mockito/mockito/wiki/Mocking-Object-Creation) in which I present two different answers to this particular problem.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem I sure will. Thanks!

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem well, you're pointing to the Mockito Documentation, not to an specific _personal_ article.

Comment: That's correct. I wrote that article when I was a member of the Mockito development team.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem oh ok nice, the article is helpful indeed I tried the implementation on the first example but I can't get it to work - I think it goes more in line of what need to be mocked and what should be a spy, for this particular case.

Comment: Hey @DawoodibnKareem - so I went ahead and used the 1st pattern mentioned on the article and it actually worked! Thank you very much - mind posting that as an answer, so I can mark it as accepted.